# Moving file based on filename with Amazon S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

Need to move Amazon S3 files based on their **names** into **appropriate folders, that are named the same**. This is for an automation script in python on AWS. The file names increment by 1.

For instance, one would be called `my_file_section_a`, then the next would be `my_file_section_b1`, then the next would be `my_file_section_b2` and so forth. The folders would be called `my_file_section_a`, `my_file_section_b1` and so forth.

Here is the code:

```
from __future__import print_function
import boto3
import time, urllib
import json

print("*"*80)
print("Initializing...")
print("*"*80)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    source_bucket = event['Records'[0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    object_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    target_bucket = 'myfilelambdadestination'
    copy_source = {'Bucket': source_bucket, 'Key': object_key}
    print("Source bucket: ", source_bucket)
    print("Target bucket: ", target_bucket)
    print("Log Stream name: ",context.log_stream_name)
    print("Log Group name: ",context.log_group_name)
    print("Request ID: ",context.aws_request_id)
    print("Mem. limits(MB) ", context.memory_limit_in_mb)
    try:
        print("Using waiter to waiting for object to persist through s3 service")
        waiter = s3.get_waiter('object_exists')
        waiter.wait(Bucket=source_bucket, Key = object_key)
        s3.copy_object(Bucket=target_bucket, Key = object_key, CopySource = copy_source)
        return response['ContentType']
    except Exception as err:
        print("Error -" +str(err))
        return e
```

How do I have it that the files based on their names are moved to folders which are also named the same?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use a waiter. The AWS Lambda function will only be triggered after the object is created.

Comment: Your requirements are a bit unclear. Are you saying that object `foo` should be copied to `foo/foo1`, but if that object already exists, then it should be copied to `foo/foo2`?

Comment: Each file is unique in that there is only one of it's type. Say for instance the file is named my_file_section_a, then my_file_section_a1. There are folders that exist with the same exact name as the file. It would be copied only based by it's name and not copied into other folders such as my_file_section_b.

Comment: Please clarify your requirements by providing more examples. Are you saying that `foo` should go to `foo/foo`, and `bar` should go to `bar/bar`? (And _why_?)

Comment: Yes, a file name foo should go into a folder named foo. And a file named bar should go into a folder named bar. Also, these files increment alphabetically so there will be foo_2 should go into a folder named foo_2. Then there will be a file called goo which should go into a folder named goo, then another file name goo_2 which should go into a file name goo_2 and so-fourth. The goal is to have the file(s) to be moved into the same folder with the same name. The reason why is for organizational purposes and that files don't have to be manually moved into these folders.

Comment: Next question: How and when would you like the files moved? Should they be done immediately upon creation (via an S3 trigger and an AWS Lambda function), or will you run a batch script at regular intervals (on an Amazon EC2 instance or perhaps your own computer)?

Comment: Hi, I believe upon immediate creation of those files that they should be moved using AWS Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

new folder is file name without the extension. depending on what object_key looks like you may have tweak this code

```
object_key = 'my_file_section_b2.txt'
new_object_prefix = object_key.rsplit('/', 1)[-1].split('.')[0]
new_object_key = new_object_prefix + '/' + object_key
new_object_key
'my_file_section_b2/my_file_section_b2.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an AWS Lambda function that will copy an object to a directory of the same name, then delete the original object.

It will only copy objects from the *root* of the bucket, to avoid a situation where the copied object triggers the Lambda function again, causing an infinite loop. (Amazon S3 is big, but not infinite!) If your target is a different bucket, this will not be necessary.

```py
import boto3
import urllib

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # Get the bucket and object key from the Event
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
    
    # Only copy objects that were uploaded to the bucket root (to avoid an infinite loop)
    if '/' not in key:
        
        # Copy object
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        s3_client.copy_object(
            Bucket = bucket,
            Key = f"{key}/{key}",
            CopySource= {'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': key}
        )
        
        # Delete source object
        s3_client.delete_object(
            Bucket = bucket,
            Key = key
        )
```

The function requires an IAM Role with permission for `GetObject` and `PutObject` (maybe more?) on the bucket. After creating this AWS Lambda function, create an Event on the Amazon S3 bucket to trigger the function when an object is created.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've ran the script using a file i've uploaded but nothing happened in AWS.

Comment: The AWS Lambda function is indented to be triggered by an Amazon S3 Event when an object is created. It is _not_ meant to be "run" directly. So, configure the bucket to trigger the function when an object is uploaded. The Bucket and Key of the object will be automatically passed to the Lambda function, which will Copy and Delete the object.