# How to move a File from One folder to Another Folder in the same AWS S3 bucket using Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, automation, file-transfer

I am trying to Automate File movement from One folder to another folder within the same S3 bucket on the file creation event in the S3 bucket.

I was hoping to use Lambda function's triggers to do this but I feel, Lambda triggers at the Root directory level and can not use it at the Folder Level.

Example:

```
Bucket Name: my-only-s3-bucket 
Source Folder: s3://my-only-s3-bucket/Landing 
Target Folder: s3://my-only-s3-bucket/Staging
```

Requirement:

When a file gets created or uploaded into, Source Folder: `s3://my-only-s3-bucket/Landing`, it should get moved to  `s3://my-only-s3-bucket/Staging` automatically without any manual intervention

How to achieve this?

Comment: You can specify a `Prefix` on the Amazon S3 trigger to only invoke the Lambda function for a given prefix/folder. If you _do_ trigger at the root level, make sure the function doesn't cause an infinite loop by copying the object to a sub-folder, which would then invoke the Lambda function again. This loop can be cut by only moving objects created at the root level (with no subfolder). However, your need is to move between folders, so this won't be an issue.

Comment: Thank you. But I have an external system that writes, CSV files only to the Root folder (it has a limitation to write it to a subfolder in S3). Now my Lambda function should move these from the root folder to a subfolder which is in the root of same S3 bucket (as my org's cloud admins don't like the idea of creating multiple buckets and I have no say in it). My only worry is this recursion. Can it be achieved somehow as I am new to AWS? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add some logic at the start of the Lambda function that says `if '/' not in Key:` then do the move. This says "only do the move if there is _no_ slash in the filename". For an example see: [Moving file based on filename with Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67895439/174777)

Comment: Perfect, This sounds like a good plan. I will try that out and confirm. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was hoping to use Lambda function's triggers to do this but I feel, Lambda triggers at the Root directory level and can not use it at the Folder Level.

This is not true. S3 has no concept of folders. You can trigger at any "level" using a filter prefix i.e `prefix -> "Landing/"` and/or a suffix (as example ".jpg").

S3 trigger will call the lambda and pass the event with the new object as input. Then just use any language you are familiar with and use s3 copy built in function from any of the available [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/)(.Net, Java, python, etc..) to copy to the destination.

example:

```
def object_copied?(
  s3_client,
  source_bucket_name,
  source_key,
  target_bucket_name,
  target_key)

  return true if s3_client.copy_object(
    bucket: target_bucket_name,
    copy_source: source_bucket_name + '/' + source_key,
    key: target_key
  )
rescue StandardError => e
  puts "Error while copying object: #{e.message}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I shall try this

Comment: My pleasure, please remember to accept/upvote the answer so it might help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I think the concept of relative path can solve your problem. **Here's the code snippet  that solves your problem** using a library called [s3pathlib](https://s3pathlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), a objective-oriented s3 file system interface.

```py
# import the library
from s3pathlib import S3Path

# define source and target folder
source_dir = S3Path("my-only-s3-bucket/Landing/")
target_dir = S3Path("my-only-s3-bucket/Staging/")

# let's say you have a new file in Landing folder, the s3 uri is
s3_uri = "s3://my-only-s3-bucket/Landing/my-subfolder/data.csv"

# I guess you want to cut the file to the new location and delete the original one
def move_file(p_file, p_source_dir, p_target_dir):
    # validate if p_file is inside of p_source_dir
    if p_file.uri.startswith(p_source_dir.uri):
        raise ValueError

    # find new s3 path based on the relative path
    p_file_new = S3Path(
        p_target_dir, p_file.relative_to(p_source_dir)
    )

    # move
    p_file.move_to(p_file_new)

    # if you want copy you can do p_file.copy_to(p_file_new)

# then let's do your work
if __name__ == "__main__":
    move_file(
        p_file=S3Path.from_s3_uri(s3_uri),
        p_source_dir=source_dir,
        p_target_dir=target_dir,
    )
```

If you want more advanced path manipulation, you can reference this [document](https://s3pathlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-Pure-S3-Path-Manipulation/index.html). And the `S3Path.change(new_abspath, new_dirpath, new_dirname, new_basename, new_fname, new_ext)` would be the most important one you need to know.