# AWS - Merge Multiple .csv from S3 into Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have an S3 bucket that contains multiple different files by date with different schemas (they are not in sub-folders). For example:

```
FileTypeA-032323
FileTypeA-032423
FileTypeA-032523
FileTypeB-032323
FileTypeB-032423
FileTypeC-032323
FileTypeD-032423
FileTypeD-032423
FileTypeD-032523
```

I need to merge all of the files for FileTypeA into a single table, then do the same for FileTypeB, etc. The intention is to eventually connect these tables to PowerBI. Is there a way to do this using Athena if the files are not in sub-folders, or is there an easy way to create sub-folders and copy files with the same naming convention into them? New daily files of each type will continue to arrive in the original s3 location. I’ve tried a lot of different approaches and keep ending up at dead ends.

I have tried DataBrew parameterized URL functionality to create datasets for each file type but kept getting errors regarding specific files when trying to load the project. I have also tried using AWS glue but didn’t see a way to union more than two files at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creation of an **AWS Lambda function with an Amazon S3 trigger**:

- When a new object is created, S3 invokes the Lambda function
- The Lambda function examines the Key (filename) of the new object and determines where it should be moved
- The function calls `CopyObject()` to copy the object to the desired location and then calls `DeleteObject` to remove the original file (see [Moving file based on filename with Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67895439/174777))

In **Amazon Athena**, you can define an **External Table** that points to the appropriate path in the folder (eg `TypeA/`) and any queries will automatically run against all objects in that path.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to it with plain athena. You can use a special `$path` WHERE clause to query specific files.

It is explained [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/find-s3-source-file-athena-table-row) how to do it. You can create a [CTAS query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html) with athena to create a new table by selecting the file specified in `$path`.

Another option would be only add files to your partitions that you want to transform. Hence your query would only consider those.